# raspbian: Launch a program when X starts

Tags: raspbian

I wonder how it is possible to launch a program when X is loaded with raspbian. raspbian is based on Debian so I suppose the solution should be Debian-based too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> raspbian is based on Debian so I suppose the solution should be Debian-based too.

Yes, they are identical in this sense, except that the default [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) (DE) on raspbian is LXDE.  However, it is available for normal Debian (which I think uses GNOME as a default) and other distros, so if you are looking for information about it, stuff about LXDE on the Arch wiki, etc. is fine.

According to [LXDE's own wiki](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart), doing this is as simple as putting a file in `~/.config/autostart`.   That format is actually an [XDG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org) standard probably implemented by most DE's.  E.g., I notice I have some on this box, created by KDE:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Dropbox
GenericName=File Synchronizer
Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
Exec=dropbox start -i
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=dropbox
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
StartupNotify=false
```

There's some documentation for this [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/), but I imagine the simple two line example from the LXDE wiki should do for most things.